# Get all models from leaps regsubsets

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

I used regsubsets to search for models. Is it possible to automatically create all `lm` from the list of parameter selections?

```
library(leaps)
leaps<-regsubsets(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data, nbest=1, method="exhaustive")
summary(leaps)$which
  (Intercept)      x1        x2    x3                                                                                   
1        TRUE   FALSE     FALSE  TRUE                                                                                   
2        TRUE   FALSE      TRUE  TRUE                                                                                   
3        TRUE    TRUE      TRUE  TRUE
```

Now i would manually do `model_1 <- lm(y ~ x3)` and so on. How can this be automated to have them in a list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why you want a list of all models. `summary` and `coef` methods should serve you well. But I will first answer your question from a pure programming aspect, then come back to this point.

---

A simple way to do this is via `reformulate`:

```
reformulate(termlabels, response = NULL, intercept = TRUE)
```

Here is how:

```
## you are masking `leaps` and `data` function!!
leaps <- regsubsets(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data, nbest = 1, method = "exhaustive")
X <- summary(leaps)$which

xvars <- dimnames(X)[[2]][-1]  ## column names (all covariates except intercept)
responsevar <- "y"  ## name of response

lst <- vector("list", dim(X)[1])  ## set up an empty model list

## loop through all rows / model specifications
for (i in 1:dim(X)[1]) {
  id <- X[i, ]
  form <- reformulate(xvars[which(id[-1])], responsevar, id[1])
  lst[[i]] <- lm(form, data)
  }
```

There is no need for a `*apply` solution. `lm` is costly, so `for` loop has no overhead at all.

---

A faster way is to set up a model matrix containing all covariates, and select its columns dynamically (use `assign` attributes of the model matrix; especially true when you have factor variables). Model fitting is then via `.lm.fit`. However, you will have difficulty in producing model summary / prediction with raw output of `.lm.fit` unless you are a linear model guru, but I think `summary(leaps)` should return you various useful statistic already.

`leaps:::coef.regsubsets` function is an equivalence of this `.lm.fit` route. Simply do:

```
coef(leaps, 1:dim(X)[1], TRUE)
```

and you will get coefficients and variance-covariance matrix for all models.

Comment: The problems are the interactions terms...that aren't explicity in the model as variable names

Comment: Nice, is there a way to get the MSE of all regsubsets of all models?